# Restrict coupon code buy chosen currency in OpenCart

Tags: opencart, coupon

Is it possible to restrict coupon code by chosen currency in OpenCart?

E.g.
Shop had two currency XX and YY. If buyer pick XX currency, Coupon code field is visible in Shopping Cart. In other case (currency YY chosen) not.

OpenCart 2.0.3.1

Comment: What have you done so far that is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Open this file:
`catalog/controller/checkout/coupon.php` in version 2.0.3.1

find:

```
    if (empty($this->request->post['coupon'])) {
        $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_empty');

        unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
    } elseif ($coupon_info) {
        $this->session->data['coupon'] = $this->request->post['coupon'];

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
    } else {
        $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_coupon');
    }
```

change it to:

```
    if (empty($this->request->post['coupon'])) {
        $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_empty');

        unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
    } elseif ($coupon_info) {
        // here I use USD for example
        if($this->session->data['currency'] == 'USD'){
            $this->session->data['coupon'] = $this->request->post['coupon'];

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
        } else {
            // Write your custom error message here
            $json['error'] = 'This coupon is only available in USD';

            unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
        }
    } else {
        $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_coupon');
    }
```